# Scrapy - Retrieve Authentication Token from javascript script response

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapy-shell

I need help about this specific scenario.

**Scenario**

1. Calling site

> http://www.example.com/index.php

I can get this information from `<script>` tag

> https://www.example.com/anotherpage.php?key=ABCDFG

using the key , I have to call this endpoint

> https://www.example.com/login.php?key=ABCD

for retrieving the SessionID which is stored inside the javascript response

```
-- omitted

private._sessID='MYSESSIONID';

-- omitted
```

At the end, using this sessionId and performing right POST actions , I can navigate inside all pages I need.

**My stalemate**

I'm able to simulate all steps using `scrapy shell` with `regEx` (and all work fine), but I don't know how to manage these steps inside a scrapy spider before starting data extraction.

Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to start with base URL `http://www.example.com/index.php` by calling it in start request method and write its callback and extract information from other endpoint and take that result into other callback and then you can start **scraping** process.

You need to implement in the following way

```
class CrawlSpider(scrapy.CrawlSpider):

   def parse_authentication_token(self, response):
      //extract token or whatever require and then call supers parse
      yield from super().parse()

   def start_requests(self):
       return Request(url, callback=self.parse_authentication_token)
```

Comment: Thank you Ahmed. Generally speaking I understood what you mean , but my problem is how to manage that inside a python spider code. Any suggestions with code sample ?

Comment: I have just updated the answer with some updated code which can guide you

Comment: Shouldn't `start_request` actually be `start_requests`?

Comment: @Kalle yes it's start requests. Updated the answer.